# Is it (reasonably) save to install wechat on my linux?

Tags: software

Apparently it is possible to install wechat on Linux [now](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/install-wechat-linux), which I would like to do. I have no illusions that my conversation might be monitored by wechat itself or the Chinese government. However, I have concerns that wechat might also compromise my OS itself (e.g. scanning my hard drive and sending data to the company). I guess there is also no guarantee that this is not the case as it could be malicious by design, is there? But is this just hypothetical or is there serious reason of concern so that I should should refrain from installing it?

My Linux OS is a Kubuntu 14.4 (yes it is a little old, and I plan to update at some point in the near future).

Answer (score 1):

The [Electronic WeChat](https://github.com/geeeeeeeeek/electronic-wechat) client is a third-party client, not an official WeChat product. Barring any unintentional security vulnerabilities in the software, it should probably be safe to use.

However, it has also been unmaintained since mid-2017. According to the project description, WeChat has taken steps to block access from third-party clients, so it's unlikely that the client will even work.